# ASP.NET MVC Web API Thread issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, multithreading, asp.net-web-api, iis-7.5, azure-web-app-service

Since a month I'm experiencing a problem that seems to be very difficult to diagnose. 
Our ASP.NET Web API runs on Azure and is hosted in a Web App, CPU and Memory usage are both between 40 and 60%.

Sometimes it happens that the metric "Threads" explodes. When it happens in an exponential way, the API becomes unresponsive and we start seeing 502 and 503 errors. My resarches states that the .NET CLR is not able to serve new requests because all threads are busy and the IIS queue becomes full.
Is this a right assumption?

Now, if I track the total number of requests, I see NO raise AT ALL during those peak times. Everything seems in a normal usage / pressure. It must be, then, some call or something that must spin new threads and block everything, I guess. 
If even this is a right assumption, how can I  diagnose WHO is spinning all these threads or WHOM are this threads linked to?

Comment: Troubleshooting can start from https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jpsanders/2017/02/02/how-to-get-a-full-memory-dump-in-azure-app-services/

Comment: I don't think that a memory dump would help me. Memory is not under pressure.

Comment: No surprise you don’t know the usage of dump analysis.

Comment: I must admit that I used different tools (like Ants) and I also tried to dump few days ago as stated in the link but I couldn't find any clue in the dump. Do you have any link on how to perform a dump analysis? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the azure app service front-end has the request timeout limit. If you exceed the limit it will return 502 or 503 error. According to your description, I guess there is some method in your codes which block the thread, we need to analysis the dump to find out which thread. I suggest you could try to use [Debug Diagnostic Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49924) to do some analysis. If you still couldn't find out some useful information, I suggest you could try to create a [support ticket](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/create-ticket/) to ask azure support for help.

Comment: I cannot understand why these threads seems to stay in the WAIT status. I don't know which threads are there. I tried to generate a memory dump from KUDU, but I cannot understand how to analyize it. Today the total thread count exploded to over 2000+. I just succeeded in downloading a profiling session, but not clue inside at all.

Comment: Yes, if we want to analysis the dump file we need use windbg to analysis it. For some special thread we also need special pdb, then we could find how the thread works.

Comment: I tried my best using windbg but seems to be created by Gods for Gods. Currently inspecting Jetbrains Dotmemory.